# How to change value of JSpinner when it's out of range?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jspinner

A **JSpinner** have a certain range, even so this jSpinner can get values out of range. What I want is that if the actual value is out of range, when I increase/decrease the jSpinner through his buttons, this "jumps" automatically to the minimum/maximum value.

e.g:

```
JSpinner s = new JSpinner();
s.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(50, 50, 250, 1)); 
//init=50, min=50, max=250, step size=1


//internal modification of s
s.setValue(0);
```

Now in the GUI I see a 0. If I increase **s**, this should do it from 50.

PS: Actually, if the value is out of rang, I'm not alowed to increase/decrease (at the interface).

Comment: not (from editor stays last value) and not (from AbstractButtons isn't possible to overloading range sets in SpinnerNumberModel), yes is posible to input non_numeric chars to editor (not asked, but notice about)

Comment: Changed my mind. In design terms it's better to don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can overide method of `SpinnerNumberModel`

```
public Object getNextValue() {
     Number original=super.getNextValue();
     //do your transformations here
     return originalTransformed; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is probably to check if a given value is in the allowed range for the spinner before setting it's value. I've used code similar to the following:

```
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;

private boolean isInRange(int val, JSpinner spinner) {
  SpinnerNumberModel model = (SpinnerNumberModel) spinner.getModel();
  int compareMin = model.getMinimum().compareTo(val), 
    compareMax = model.getMaximum().compareTo(val);

  return (compareMin <= 0 && compareMax >= 0)
}

private void setValue(int val, JSpinner spinner) {
  if (isInRange(val, spinner))
   spinner.setValue(val);
  else {
    Object defaultVal = spinner.getNextValue();
    if (defaultVal != null)
      spinner.setValue(defaultVal)
    else
      spinner.setValue(spinner.getPreviousValue());
  }
}
```